# Jquery chosen ajax call populate multiselelect not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a Jquery chosen multiselectlist to add events to a meeting based
on the type of sport selected in a dropdown that contains a swimming and an athletics string.
When I select swimming only swimming events should be available in de chosen list
, same thing for athletics. Ajax is kinda new for me and is giving me some problems.
As you can see in the following image, there is also a non-athletics event in the list
(Event_100m_Breaststroke).

http://oi43.tinypic.com/1tocvs.jpg

I am using MVC 4 and the Entity Framework

Dropdown:

```
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Meeting.RegionId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.RegionId, "...")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Meeting.RegionId)
```

Multiselect:

```
        @Html.ListBox("Events", ViewBag.Eventslist as MultiSelectList,
               new { @class = "chzn-select", data_placeholder = "Choose  event(s)...", style = "width:350px;", id = "select1" })
```

Ajax call:

```
$("#Meeting_Sport").change(function () {
    var _this = document.getElementById('Meeting_Sport');
    var thisValue = _this.options[_this.selectedIndex].value;

    $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetEventsAjax")/" + _this.value, function (data) {
        if (data.Status == "Success") {
            var possibilities = "";
            var items = "";

            $.each(data.Events, function (index, item) {
                possibilities += '<li id="' + 'select1_chzn_o_' + data.EventsId[index] + '" class="active-result style="">"' + item + '"</li>';
                items += "<option value='" + data.EventsId[index] + "'>" + item + "</option>";
            });

            $(".chzn-results").children().remove().end();
            $("#select1").children().remove().end();

            $("#select1").html(items);
            $(".chzn-results").html(possibilities);

            $("label[for='input01']").show();
            $("#input01").show();
            $("#select1_chzn").show();

            var items = "";
            var possibilities = "";
        }
    });
})
```

Json get method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetEventsAjax(String id)
    {
        try
        {
            List<String> Events = db.Events.Where(e => e.Sport == id).Select(e => e.Name).ToList();
            List<int> EventsId = db.Events.Where(e => e.Sport == id).Select(e => e.EventId).ToList();

            return Json(new { Status = "Success", Events = Events, EventsId = EventsId }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Json(new { Status = "Failure", Message = e.Message });
        }
    }
```

The weird thing is that when I for example select swimming this will be the result:
http://oi41.tinypic.com/2ilklle.jpg
As you can see only swimming events are listed in the above part but don't appear in the multiselect list, only those in the chzn-results appear. What can I do to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe not the only reason for your problem but you are missing a double quote `'" class="active-result style="">"'` after `active-result` which breaks your html `<li id="select1_chzn_o_3" class="active-result style=" ">`.

Comment: Ah this was indeed an error but it did not resolve the problem :)

Comment: Are there any script errors in the console? Put a debugger break in your action -- Is your action returning the correct data set?

Comment: It is returning the correct data set